# Executar função javascript em uma página especifica

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Tenho um site wordpress multilingual com o plugin WPML preciso executar um a função javascript que chama um modal, apenas em uma das versões do site, é possível que ela seja executada pela url especifica? como posso fazer isso? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente capture a URL do browser com window.location.pathname função do javascript, depois verifica se a url é igual a url especifica:

```
var urlEspecifica = window.location.pathname == "sua url especifica aqui";
if(urlEspecifica ){
   //sua função aqui
 }
```